# Как сделать такие углы?

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать такие углы у div с помощью css?
[image: Углы]

Comment: В правой колонке есть несколько ссылок на похоже вопросы.

Comment: Эти углы немного отличаются

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как-то так

```css
div{
  max-width:300px;
  margin:20px auto;
  background-color:#cda;
  border-radius:10px/20px ;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```